# Type guards for function in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I've defined a type `Filter` in TypeScript, which can be `string`, `RegExp` or `Predicator`, which is a function. Type defines are listed below.

```
export type Predicator = (input: string) => boolean;
export type SingleFilter = string | RegExp | Predicator;
```

There's a function taking `SingleFilter` as input. However, the type guards seems to be not working with `Predicator`, as long as `RegExp` presists.
But the issue is gone if the type is `string | Predicator` only.

```
function singlePredicator(value: any) {
  if (typeof value === 'string') {
    // do something for string
  }
  else if (value instanceof RegExp) {
    // do something
  }
  else {
    // do something for function
    // Error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature.
    value(foo);
  }
}
```

Is there any solution to make it work in my case? Thanks. I'm using `tsc` 1.5.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first change in the example below is that I have typed the `value` paramater as a `SingleFilter` rather than `any.

The second change is the type assertion in the last `else` statement to hint to the compiler that `value` is a `Predicator`.

```
export type Predicator = (input: string) => boolean;
export type SingleFilter = string | RegExp | Predicator;

function singlePredicator(value: SingleFilter) {
  if (typeof value === 'string') {
    // do something for string
    return value.charAt(0);
  } else if (value instanceof RegExp) {
    // do something
    value.test("Something");
  } else {
    // do something for function
    var foo = "SomeFoo";
    value(foo);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works now. But still, is there any way to have a type guard working on functions?

Comment: If you had a union type of `string|Function`, it would work as expected. http://bit.ly/1NAKB3B - same goes for `string|number|Function` so the problem stems from the instanceof check on RegExp.

Comment: Thanks, it make sense for my case :)

Comment: The type assertion should not be necessary anymore (at least since Typescript 2.0)

Comment: Updated - thanks @AJRichardson - it is so hard to keep all the answers up to date ;)